# jQuery isotope weird behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I'm using a Wordpress template that use jQuery isotope to sort portfolio items, and i like the isotope effects.

One problem i'm facing it that when i resize the window the plugin resize the boxes and move them weirdly.

I'm analysing the scripts and the logs and i can't find out the problem.

I'll appreciate your help or your ideas to fix this.

http://uniteworks.com/jquery.isotope.html

Thank you

Comment: This site uses so very many scripts, it would take forever to go through to find clashing scripts, scripts you may have modified, etc. Maybe first look out for everything setting and modifying margins and positioning, going through all scripts that have a handle on that. Maybe something is also wrong in the columnWidth setting of the Isotope plugin...

Comment: Yes someone tweaked the original layout. I need to compare this to the original template ! but unfotunately i can't find the same version.

Comment: If you look at the original http://spadeinvaders.com/themes/elastico/ - which is what I did - with Chrome's devtools, you can see all resources the template pulls in. Since that one works, I'd rather use that than the tweaked version for which you probably can't know what was tweaked and where and why...